# rails: multiple OR statements in current_page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Why does this code set li class active for only the spree.account_url and ignores the rest even though when only one of the others are valid?

```
<li class='<%= "active" if current_page?(spree.account_url || edit_user_newsletter_path || orders_path || nilecard_path) %>'>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this doesn't work the way you think it does.

```
spree.account_url || edit_user_newsletter_path
```

edit_user_newsletter_path will *only* be returned if spree.account_url is nil.  It's not nil, so spree.account_url is always returned in preference for anything else.

Better would be...

```
<li class='<%= "active" if [spree.account_url, edit_user_newsletter_path, orders_path, nilecard_path].map{|p| current_page?(p)}.any? %>'>
```